# MDX Parameters in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssas, mdx, ssrs-2008-r2

Good Day all, hope that someone can assist I have the following member that I am creating, this is how the code looks which works hard coded.

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[CoinInRank] AS CASE 
WHEN [Measures].[Total Amount Bet] <= 5100  AND [Measures].[Total Amount Bet] > 0 THEN "Casual"
WHEN [Measures].[Total Amount Bet] > 5100 AND [Measures].[Total Amount Bet] <=  25000 THEN "Frequent"
WHEN [Measures].[Total Amount Bet] > 25000 THEN "Avid"
END MEMBER
```

Now I would like to pass the amount ranges i.e 5100 and 25000 as parameters from SSRS, I have tried the following with absolutely no luck.

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[CoinInRank] AS CASE 
WHEN [Measures].[Total Amount Bet] <= STRTOSET(@FrequentMinValue,CONSTRAINED)   AND [Measures].[Total Amount Bet] > 0 THEN "Casual"
WHEN [Measures].[Total Amount Bet] > STRTOSET(@FrequentMinValue,CONSTRAINED) AND [Measures].[Total Amount Bet] <=  STRTOSET(@FrequentMaxValue,CONSTRAINED) THEN "Frequent"
WHEN [Measures].[Total Amount Bet] >  STRTOSET(@FrequentMaxValue,CONSTRAINED)  THEN "Avid"
END MEMBER
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

StrToSet converts a string into a set. Measures is a numeric expression so comparing to a set will not work. If you get rid of the StrToSet what happens?

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[CoinInRank] AS CASE 
WHEN [Measures].[Total Amount Bet] <= @FrequentMinValue   AND [Measures].[Total Amount Bet] > 0 THEN "Casual"
WHEN [Measures].[Total Amount Bet] > @FrequentMinValue AND [Measures].[Total Amount Bet] <=  @FrequentMaxValue THEN "Frequent"
WHEN [Measures].[Total Amount Bet] >  @FrequentMaxValue THEN "Avid"
END MEMBER
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to re-check your syntax here. The `MEMBER` at the end doesn't look like it belongs here.

The syntax for `CASE` is

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].x AS 
CASE 
   WHEN 1>2 THEN 'false'
   WHEN 2>1 THEN 'true'
   ELSE 'none'
END
```

Since you pull the value from report, the value is going to be in string format. I am not sure if `MDX` engine allows a numeric value to be compared against a string.So to be on the safer side, you might need to use the `StrToValue` function to convert that text value to numeric.

Your final query should look like -

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[CoinInRank] AS CASE 
WHEN [Measures].[Total Amount Bet] <= STRTOVALUE(@FrequentMinValue,CONSTRAINED)   
AND [Measures].[Total Amount Bet] > 0 
   THEN "Casual"
WHEN [Measures].[Total Amount Bet] > STRTOVALUE(@FrequentMinValue,CONSTRAINED) 
AND [Measures].[Total Amount Bet] <=  STRTOVALUE(@FrequentMaxValue,CONSTRAINED)
   THEN "Frequent"
WHEN [Measures].[Total Amount Bet] >  STRTOVALUE(@FrequentMaxValue,CONSTRAINED)  
   THEN "Avid"
END
```

Hope it helps you.